# Can I add a module import inside of forRoot/forChild method?

Tags: angular

I have a SharedModule which has a forRoot and forChild method to import it in AppModule or lazy modules. I do not know or do not know how i can import one module inside of these methods. The point is that i use ngx-translate that need a TranslateModule.forRoot({config}) for AppModule and TranslateModule.forFeature({config}) for the rest of modules.

For example doing some like this:

```
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: [...SharedModule, TranslateModule.forRoot({config})],
      providers: [
        { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MyDateAdapter },
        MainUiHelper,
        FilterLinksHelper,
        FormattingHelper
      ]
    };
  }
  static forChild(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: [...SharedModule, TranslateModule.forChild({config})]
    };
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!!